# Adobe Window too big

Tags: windows-7

In e-mail I'm being sent some data but when I download it, the adobe window pops up and all action is frozen.  When I scroll through the adobe contract and want to click on "apply" or "yes?". those buttons are not visible - they are belos the monitor screen.  I assume until I can accept adobe's terms, I wont be able to receive any data sent through the e-mail

.

Answer (score 0):

Left-click the icon in the top-left corner of the Adobe window, or right-click the title bar, or hit alt-space. From the resulting menu, choose "move". Then, you can use the cursor keys to move the window around until you can see the button you need to click.